# How to solve subquery returned more than 1

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm having a problem in my subquery select frequency and display

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT desc_category 
     FROM category 
     WHERE code = id_category) AS Category, 
   notes AS 'Description',
   end_date AS 'Due Date',
   (SELECT frequency 
    FROM category_schedule2 
    WHERE notes = description 
    GROUP BY frequency) 
FROM
    category_schedule
```

This is my table category_schedule2

```
SELECT * 
FROM category_schedule2 
WHERE description = 'sunlife'
```

| description | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| SUNLIFE | ANNUAL |
| SUNLIFE | SEMI-ANNUAL |
| SUNLIFE | SEMI-ANNUAL |

This is my target output:

| Category | Description | Due Date | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wifi | PLDT | 2023-12-31 | MONTHLY |
| Sample | SUNLIFE | 2023-12-31 | ANNUAL |
| Codename | Bar | 2023-01-01 | SEMI-ANNUAL |
| Wifi | SUNLIFE | 2023-01-01 | SEMI-ANNUAL |

Comment: Fix your subquery so that it returns only one row, by specifying a better WHERE clause, a JOIN, or using DISTINCT. In the future, please search this site for the error message before asking a new question, as chances are good someone has asked about it before. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Subquery+returns+more+than+1+row

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Clearly this can expected to be a faq or faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Your subquery returns more than 1 row. Do you want all of them, or just one (which one)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got one product specific answer...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.desc_category AS Category, 
       notes AS 'Description',
       end_date AS 'Due Date',
       DS.frequency
FROM category_schedule CS
INNER JOIN category C
    ON CS.id_category = c.code
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT frequency 
    FROM category_schedule2 
    WHERE notes = CS.description 
    GROUP BY frequency 
) DS
```